# How to define a tree-like DAG in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

How do you define a **directed acyclic graph** (DAG) (of strings) (with one root) best in **Haskell**?

I especially need to apply the following two functions on this data structure as fast as possible:

1. Find all (direct and indirect) ancestors of one element (including the parents of the parents etc.).
2. Find all (direct) children of one element.

I thought of `[(String,[String])]` where each pair is one element of the graph consisting of its name (`String`) and a list of strings (`[String]`) containing the names of (direct) parents of this element. The problem with this implementation is that it's hard to do the second task.

You could also use `[(String,[String])]` again while the list of strings (`[String]`) contain the names of the (direct) children. But here again, it's hard to do the first task.

What can I do? What alternatives are there? Which is the most efficient way?

**EDIT:** One more remark: I'd also like it to be defined easily. I have to define the instance of this data type myself "by hand", so i'd like to avoid unnecessary repetitions.

Comment: `data Family = Ego { parents, children :: [String] }; type DAG = Map String Family`? If you store parents as well as children, both find operations should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Or have two maps. One from parents to children, second from children to parents. Choose the way fits you best.

Comment: I added an additional remark in the original question which makes your suggetion difficult.

Comment: @MekeorMelire Define your own map-like datatype. You can start with `type Map k v = [(k, v)]`.

Comment: That would not help, as far as I can see.

Comment: Cheap, fast, correct, pick two. Err, you can have two of 1. easy/fast finding of parents, 2. easy/fast finding of children, 3. simple representation. Consider the tradeoffs and take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [the tree implemention in Martin Erwig's Functional Graph Library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/latest/doc/html/Data-Graph-Inductive-Tree.html)? Each node is represented as a context containing both its children and its parents. See the [graph](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/latest/doc/html/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html) type class for how to access this. It might not be as easy as you requested, but it is already there, well-tested and easy-to-use. I have used it for more than a decade in a large project.

Comment: Any idea about its speed over Haskell maps? I want to use this library but my graphs are pretty big.